# singleton java class returning null value

Tags: java, singleton

I created a java class which return a DB connection object. But it is returning the null value at the caller method. When i am running the code in debug mode it is not going to the method itself. Need suggestions.

```
package com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class CreateConnection {

    private static Connection instance = null;
    static final String drivername = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

    private CreateConnection() {

        try {
            Class.forName(drivername);
            // instance =
            // DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://hddev-c01-edge-01:20000/",
            // "phodisvc", "B1GD4T4dev");
            // for hive 1 use this ------> instance =
            // DriverManager.getConnection("thrift://hddev-c01-edge-02:9083");
            instance = DriverManager.getConnection("thrift://hddev-c01-edge-02:9083");
            System.out.println("get instance"+instance);
            Constants.setFlag(true);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Constants.setFlag(false);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Constants.setFlag(false);
        }
    }

    public static Connection getInstance() {
        Constants.setFlag(true);
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Below is the code which is calling the getInstance() method

```
package com.cisco.installbase.hiveconnector;

import java.util.Date;

public class MainApp {

    private static final String hiveDB = ReadProperties.getInstance().getProperty("hive_db");
    private static final String logTable = ReadProperties.getInstance().getProperty("IB_log_table");
    private static final String dataGovernanceLogTable = ReadProperties.getInstance().getProperty("SR_DG_table");
    private static final String dataGovernanceMasterTable = ReadProperties.getInstance()
            .getProperty("SR_DG_master_table");

    private static final String count_xxccs_ds_sahdr_core = "select count(*) from " + hiveDB + "."
            + "xxccs_ds_sahdr_core";
    private static final String count_mtl_system_items_b = "select count(*) from " + hiveDB + "."
            + "mtl_system_items_b";
    private static final String count_xxccs_scdc_product_profile = "select count(*) from " + hiveDB + "."
            + "xxccs_scdc_product_profile";
    private static final String count_xxccs_ds_cvdprdline_detail = "select count(*) from " + hiveDB + "."
            + "xxccs_ds_cvdprdline_detail";
    private static final String count_xxccs_ds_instance_detail = "select count(*) from " + hiveDB + "."
            + "xxccs_ds_instance_detail";

    private static int currentJobID = 0;
    private static Date startTime = null;
    private static Date stopTime = null;
    private static int runTime = 0;

    static CommonDBUtilities commonDB = new CommonDBUtilities();
    static ShellUtilities shellUtilities = new ShellUtilities();
    static SqoopUtility sqoop = new SqoopUtility();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MainApp.startTimeLogger();
        System.out.println("Started the Job");

    }

    public static void startTimeLogger() {
        // getting the Job ID and the start time for the log table

        if (Constants.isFlag()) {
            currentJobID = commonDB.getMaximumJobID();
            startTime = commonDB.getTime();
            MainApp.importTables();
            System.out.println("executing startTimeLogger");
        } else {
            MainApp.onFailure();
            JobMailer.PostMail("IB Load Failed", "Load failed while logging method name startTimeLogger()");
            System.out.println("executing startTimeLogger failed");
        }
    }

    public static void importTables() {
        // Delete target directory before running the sqoop imports

        if (Constants.isFlag()) {
            shellUtilities.DeleteDirectory(Constants.getMtlSystems());
            shellUtilities.DeleteDirectory(Constants.getProductLine());
            shellUtilities.DeleteDirectory(Constants.getInstanceDetail());
            shellUtilities.DeleteDirectory(Constants.getProductLine());
            shellUtilities.DeleteDirectory(Constants.getHeaderCore());

            // Run the sqoop imports to load the data from oracle to hive

            sqoop.runSqoop();
            MainApp.getCounts();
            System.out.println("executing importTables");
        } else {
            MainApp.onFailure();
            JobMailer.PostMail("IB Load Failed", "Load failed while running sqoop import method name importTables()");
            System.out.println("executing importTables failed");
        }

    }

    public static void getCounts() {

        // Get the record counts for all the IB tables pulled

        if (Constants.isFlag()) {
            commonDB.getCounts(count_xxccs_ds_instance_detail);
            commonDB.getCounts(count_xxccs_ds_cvdprdline_detail);
            commonDB.getCounts(count_xxccs_scdc_product_profile);
            commonDB.getCounts(count_mtl_system_items_b);
            commonDB.getCounts(count_xxccs_ds_sahdr_core);
            MainApp.stopTimeLogger();
            System.out.println("executing getCounts");
        } else {
            MainApp.onFailure();
            JobMailer.PostMail("IB Load Failed", "Load failed while getting counts method name getCounts()");
            System.out.println("executing getCounts failed");
        }
    }

    public static void stopTimeLogger() {
        // Get the stop time or end time
        if (Constants.isFlag()) {
            stopTime = commonDB.getTime();
            MainApp.runTimeLogger();
            System.out.println("executing stopTimeLogger");
        } else {
            MainApp.onFailure();
            JobMailer.PostMail("IB Load Failed", "Load failed while end logging method name stopTimeLogger()");
            System.out.println("executing stopTimeLogger failed");
        }
    }

    public static void runTimeLogger() {
        // Get the run time or total time taken
        if (Constants.isFlag()) {
            runTime = (int) (stopTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
            MainApp.onSuccess();
            MainApp.logGovernance();
            System.out.println("executing runTimeLogger");
        } else {
            MainApp.onFailure();
            JobMailer.PostMail("IB Load Failed", "Load failed while runtime logging method name runTimeLogger()");
            System.out.println("executing runTimeLogger failed");
        }
    }

    public static void logGovernance() {
        // IB Data governance

        if (Constants.isFlag()) {
            String dataGovernance = "Insert into table " + hiveDB + "." + dataGovernanceLogTable
                    + " select Data_Asset_Reference,File_Name,Origin_System,Transfer_System," + startTime
                    + ",Column_Reference,Element_Reference,Rule_Priority,Delete_By_Date,Classification,Geographic_Inclusion,Geographic_Restriction,Group_Inclusion,Group_Restriction,Reserved from "
                    + hiveDB + "." + dataGovernanceMasterTable;
            commonDB.InsertToTable(dataGovernance);
            System.out.println("executing logGovernance");
        } else {
            MainApp.onFailure();
            JobMailer.PostMail("IB Load Failed",
                    "Load failed while inserting into datagovernance method name logGovernance()");
            System.out.println("executing logGovernance failed");
        }
    }

    public static void onFailure() {
        // Write to log on Failure
        String insertOnFailure = "insert into table " + hiveDB + "." + logTable + " select " + currentJobID + ","
                + stopTime + "," + runTime + "," + "FAILED from " + hiveDB + "." + "dual" + " limit 1; ";
        commonDB.InsertToTable(insertOnFailure);
        JobMailer.PostMail("IB Load Failed", "Load failed");
        System.out.println("executing onFailure");
    }

    public static void onSuccess() {
        // Write to log on Success
        String insertOnSuccess = "insert into table " + hiveDB + "." + logTable + " select " + currentJobID + ","
                + stopTime + "," + runTime + "," + "SUCCESS from " + hiveDB + "." + "dual" + " limit 1; ";
        commonDB.InsertToTable(insertOnSuccess);
        JobMailer.PostMail("IB Load Successfully completed", "Load completed");
        System.out.println("executing onSuccess");
    }

}
```

Comment: Your implementation of singleton pattern is wrong

Comment: That is not really a singleton pattern, since you have a `CreateConnection` class (which you never really create or care about its instance), but in `getInstance()` return a `Connection` object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of sigleton is wrong.
You never call the constructor.  This is th correct way to implement a singleton.

```
public static Connection getInstance() {
        if (instance==null){
            instance = new CreateConnection();
        }
        Constants.setFlag(true);
        return instance;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 private static Connection instance = null;
    static final String drivername = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";



    public static Connection getInstance() {
        if(instance==null){
        try {
            Class.forName(drivername);
            instance = DriverManager.getConnection("thrift://hddev-c01-edge-02:9083");
            Constants.setFlag(true);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Constants.setFlag(false);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Constants.setFlag(false);
        }       
    }
    return instance;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You never call the constructor `CreateConnection()` (besides, this shouldn't be a constructor anyway, rather a utility method returning a Connection).